# How to mock a static method which be called by another static method?

Tags: java, mocking

I want test a static method A which calls another static method B in same class. How can I mock up the method B?

Comment: I have test it with Mockito, EasyMock.expect, PowerMock.mockStatic, PowerMock.replay and PowerMockito. But not working.

Comment: If you want to mock methods like this I wouldn't use static methods.  It suggests you should re-think your design if you need to do this.

Comment: Peter: Thanks for your advice. But I can not change the design. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Mocking static methods
Quick summary

```
Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
Use PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to mock all methods of this class.
Use PowerMock.replay(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to replay mode.
Use PowerMock.verify(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to verify mode.
```

Example
Mocking a static method in PowerMock requires the use of the "mockStatic" method in PowerMock. Let's say you have a class, ServiceRegistrator, with a method called registerService that looks like this:

```
public long registerService(Object service) {
   final long id = IdGenerator.generateNewId();
   serviceRegistrations.put(id, service);
   return id;
}
```

The point of interest here is the static method call to IdGenerator.generateNewId() which we would like to mock. IdGenerator is a helper class that simply generates a new ID for the service. It looks like this:

```
public class IdGenerator {

   /**
    * @return A new ID based on the current time.
    */
   public static long generateNewId() {
      return System.currentTimeMillis();
   }
}
```

With PowerMock it's possible to expect the call to IdGenerator.generateNewId() just as you would with any other method using EasyMock once you've told PowerMock to prepare the IdGenerator class for testing. You do this by adding an annotation to the class-level of test case. This is simply done be using @PrepareForTest(IdGenerator.class). You also need to tell JUnit to execute the test using PowerMock which is done by using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class). Without these two annotations the test will fail.

The actual test is then actually quite simple:

```
@Test
public void testRegisterService() throws Exception {
        long expectedId = 42;

        // We create a new instance of test class under test as usually.
        ServiceRegistartor tested = new ServiceRegistartor();

        // This is the way to tell PowerMock to mock all static methods of a
        // given class
        mockStatic(IdGenerator.class);

        /*
         * The static method call to IdGenerator.generateNewId() expectation.
         * This is why we need PowerMock.
         */
        expect(IdGenerator.generateNewId()).andReturn(expectedId);

        // Note how we replay the class, not the instance!
        replay(IdGenerator.class);

        long actualId = tested.registerService(new Object());

        // Note how we verify the class, not the instance!
        verify(IdGenerator.class);

        // Assert that the ID is correct
        assertEquals(expectedId, actualId);
}
```

Note that you can mock static methods in a class even though the class is final. The method can also be final. To mock only specific static methods of a class refer to the partial mocking section in the documentation.

[Reference: powermock wiki](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)

Comment: Oleksandr: Thanks for your answer. If the method be tested is not a static method, it is working. But if the method is a static method and in IdGenerator class, you solution will has issues. Like below:
public class IdGenerator {
    /**
     * @return A new ID based on the current time.
     */
    public static long generateNewId() {
       return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    
    public static long registerService(Object service) {
        final long id = IdGenerator.generateNewId();
        //serviceRegistrations.put(id, service);
        return id;
     }
}

Answer (score -1):

If both functions are in same class then call simply without using any object or class name.If they are in different functions then using class name you can call each other.Hope this will help you. :)